# leap year - by only using arithmetical operators in C

Tags: c, leap-year

I have the weirdest exercise I've ever seen: I have to find a leap year by scanning a year in the console and to control if that is a leap year.

I can *only* use `+ - / * %` as arithmetical operators; I am not allowed to use any other operators or functions.

Here is what I have so far:

```c
   int year = 0;
   bool b = false;
    
   printf ("Type in a year: ");
    
   int helpVar = 1000;
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       year += (getchar() - '0') * helpVar;
       helpVar = helpVar / 10;
   }
    
   b = (((year % 4) + (year % 100) + (year % 400)) + 1) % 2;
```

So I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. It works so far, the only case that's freaking me out is for year "1900". It shouldn't be a leap year, but appears to, by my code.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code also uses `<`, `++`, `+=` and `=`. Or do these not count?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Well then, none of my leap years e.g. "2000" or "1904" is a leap year

Comment: @chtz for the initialization of "b" I am not allowed to use other operators than +, -, *, / and %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility (perhaps not the shortest -- obviously only works for the Gregorian calendar):

```
b = (((year-1)%4)+1)/4 - (((year-1)%100)+1)/100 + (((year-1)%400)+1)/400;
```

The idea is that `((year-1) % n) + 1` equals `n` only if `year` is a multiple of `n` (for positive `year`), and is smaller than `n` otherwise. Thus, if you divide that by `n`, you get `1` if and only if `(year % n == 0)`.

Since `year%100==0` cannot be true if `year%4==0` is not, you can subtract that from each other, but add the `year%400==0` term at the end.

Comment: Well that makes sense, but I'll be honest. This is one of the most senseless exercises I've ever gotten. Thank you, I understand your logic, but tbh I thought way differently than you did. Thanks for clearing me up!

Comment: @auroNpls: It might seem like a strange exercise, but there can be good reasons for writing code like this: one is that it avoids branches (which, depending on the CPU's ability to do branch prediction, can have performance implications). Another is that it means the runtime is independent of the input, which is important in cryptographic code to avoid leaking information about secret material. (I don't know whether that's what your instructor had in mind, but I hope it provides some motivation either way!)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `%` operations are done in *integer* arithmetic and, as such, their results may well be values other than `0` or `1`. However, if you cast each of those results to the `bool` type (assuming that is as defined in the `<stdbool.h>` header), then your formula will work:

```c
    b = (((bool)(year % 4) + (bool)(year % 100) + (bool)(year % 400)) + 1) % 2;
```

The only modifications I've made to your code is to add the `(bool)` casts on the results of each of the `%` operations.

---

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the above solution 'breaks the rules' by using the cast **operator**. The following modification also works (in a similar way), but it uses the `!` operator (twice) on each `%` result; this also breaks the rules, but it may be nice for posterity:

```c
    b = ((!!(year % 4) + !!(year % 100) + !!(year % 400)) + 1) % 2;
```

---

A modification of this solution using only *implicit* type conversions to `bool` (thus not using cast operators) would appear to be within the rules. This can be done using temporary/intermediate variables to hold the results of each `%` operation:

```c
    bool four = year % 4, hundred = year % 100, fourhund = year % 400;
    b = (four + hundred + fourhund + 1) % 2;
```

Or, you could pre-declare the three intermediate `bool` variables and then do those implicit type conversions 'inline', like this:

```c
    bool m4, m100, m400; // You could also move this to where you declare "b"
    b = (((m4 = year % 4) + (m100 = year % 100) + (m400 = year % 400)) + 1) % 2;
```

Comment: well, you are right. so it was only the casting that went wrong. thank you! :)

Comment: Isn't `(bool) x` technically applying the cast-operator?

Comment: @chtz well, it is. I thought it was okay too, but it isnt. :) but good to know that my "formula" works, if I cast it to bool

Comment: @chtz See edit for using the same basic approach but avoiding explicit use of cast operators. Maybe not the cleanest code, though.

Answer (score 0):

From the post above, the definition of a `leap year` is that: for year `n`

- `n` should be a multiple of 4, which can be presented as `n % 4 == 0`
- `n` is a multiple of `400` or `n` is not a multiple of `100`

The problem is that you shouldn't write all those three conditions as a **addition** operation. You should write them as logical expression.

In your code:

> b = (((year % 4) + (year % 100) + (year % 400)) + 1) % 2;

there are 3 conditions, `year % 4`, `year % 100` and `year % 400`, there are two ways to make b = true after the evaluation:

- all three conditions are false
- there are one and only one case is false

### Okey, let's make it clear

**The definition of leap year:**

- `n` is multiple of 4 and not a multiple of 100
- `n` is multiple of 400

So you code can be like this:

```c
int year;
if (year % 400) {
    printf("Fine it's a leap year\n");
} else if (year % 100 == 0) {
    printf("Oh no it's not a leap year\n");
} else if (yaer % 4 == 0) {
    printf("It's a leap year\n");
} else {
    printf("Not a leap year\n");
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use logical operators, otherwise I would've done it like that. 
This is what I've also tried: `b = (((year % 4) * (year % 100) + (year % 400)) + 1) % 2;`

Comment: this still uses other operators than arithmetical operators. `==` is not an arithmetical operator, if-brackets are also not allowed